# AngularJS data binding and view change

Tags: angularjs

I understand how two-way data binding works with AngularJS but I'm struggling to make it work in a situation described below. I've a index.template.html, home.template.html, search.template.html, app.js, search.controller.js and search.service.js files. I've a input form on a home page at '/' url.

```
<li ng-controller="searchCtrl">   //searchCtrl() in search.controller.js file
  <form role="search">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchstring" 
      placeholder="Enter string here"> <br />
    <button type="submit" 
      ng-click="searchString(searchstring)">Search</button>
  </form>
</li>
```

And I've search.template.html to display the results as follows,

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1> SearchedText</h1>
  <h2> {{ searchedtext }} </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

search.controller.js is as follows,

```
(function () {
 angular
   .module('twowaybindapp')
   .controller('searchCtrl', searchCtrl);
   searchCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'SearchService'];

function searchCtrl($scope, SearchService) {
  $scope.searchString = function(searchtext) {
    SearchService
      .getSearchResults(searchtext)   //getSearchResults in search.service.js
      .success(function(data) {
        console.log('Service call is a success with result:');
        console.log(data);    
        $scope.searchedtext = data; 
      }).error(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };
}
})();
```

My app.js file is as follows,

```
  var myApp = angular.module('twowaybindapp', [ 'ngRoute' ]);
  myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'home.view.html'
      }).
      when('/search', {
        templateUrl: 'search.view.html',
        controller: 'searchCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
  }]);
```

With this background, When I've both form and results html text (content of search.template.html) in the same home.template.html, things work fine and I see all the results but if I put them in separate files as above, either I don't know how to open the results in new view after the call or don't know if data-binding is not working. I do see results in console.log() in both cases that mean service call is working okay as expected. This might be silly question but I really need help with this. Would it work if the search form is a part of navigation directive at the top of every page and results needs to be shown below in a main ng-view? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
-- Atarangp

Comment: I think I got the view part right, I got the search view display after adding an <a href ... tag to the button in the search form. Now I'm sure that data binding is not happening. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `{{smth}}` in html it parsed to `$scope.smth`, each controller has its own scope object, by default scopes are nested:

```
<div ng-controller="c1" ng-init="smth = 1">
    <div ng-controller="c2">
        {{smth}} << 1
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-controller="c3">
    {{smth}} << undefined
</div>
```

When you defined several views - they will have different scopes, so you can not see one scope from another.

Fastest way to make it work is change to `$rootScope.searchedtext = data;` cause all your scopes nests from root scope.

Other way is to make common parent state and access and set your property there.

Yet another ways are: use your own service to store data, pass data using events, pass data using properties in state obj...